# date_i18n in wordpress/php

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, internationalization

I am working on a html/php code as shown below:

> HTML/PHP Code:

```
<time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'H:i d-m-Y')) ?>"
   data-timezone="<?php echo esc_attr($tz_param) ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(date_i18n( 'F j H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp())); ?>
</time>
```

The above **html/php** code displays the following on inspect:

```
<time datetime="02:15 19-07-2019" data-timezone="he">Juillet 19 06:15</time>
```

The time here `Juillet 19 06:15` doesn't seems to match the time here `02:15 19-07-2019` which is inside the datetime attribute

On debugging `print_r($ts)`, it prints:

```
 DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-07-19 01:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code so that the time here `Juillet 19 06:15` should be equal to the time inside datetime attribute `02:15 19-07-2019`

Comment: Can you show `$ts` object?

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui I have updated my question. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui are you around ?

Comment: I am around. Checking.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Returning the output which is desired in your case.

Comment: Add this and check does it return you correct output:
`$dateSrc = '2019-07-19 01:00:00.000000';
$ts = new DateTime($dateSrc);`